# Sprout SEO: Getting error on save, preventing updating "default" meta data

Tags: plugin-sproutseo

After creating a default meta entry in Sprout SEO. Any subsequent updates aren't saved and I get an error message "Couldn't save the default"

Using:

- Craft 2.4.2725
- Sprout SEO 1.1.1

Has anyone else come across this?

Comment: Do you see any related errors in your logs (craft/storage/runtime/logs/sproutseo.log)?

Comment: I don't see a sproutseo.log but I do see craft.log. Not sure what to look for inside the craft log with no obvious errors.

Comment: The only thing I have been able to track down is that for some reason the id column of the sproutseo_defaults  table wasn't auto incrementing. The first entry would result in a 0. haven't been able to figure out why.

Answer (score 2):

This issue came as a result of the MySQL DB `sql_mode` including the `NO_AUTO_VALUE_ON_ZERO` mode which affects how `auto_increment` columns work. When trying to create a new row entry it will only `auto_increment` if `null` is passed.

Full explanation here:

http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/sql-mode.html#sqlmode_no_auto_value_on_zero

This setting matched with the way the controller's `actionSaveDefault` function was setting the id to a blank value rather than a `null` value caused it to trigger this DB behavior of writing a 0 rather than `auto_increment`.

While the cause of the issue is not Craft or SproutSEO specific, this answer might help anyone else with the issue.

1. Check your MySQL DB `sql_mode`
2. If, `NO_AUTO_VALUE_ON_ZERO` is set make sure you're passing `null` if you want it to `auto_increment`